# Identify Empty Schedule blocks

Tags: sql

I have a query that shows all datetimes - every 30 minutes and this is matched up to a schedule.
I would like to identify the First and Last DATEDATE where the schedule is empty in each block as highlighted in my image.

[image: Empty Blocks]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is already answered... Here is an alternative answer.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
CASE  
     WHEN slots IS NULL AND LAG(slots) OVER (ORDER BY datedate,startdate,enddate,slots) > 0 THEN 'start'   
     WHEN slots IS NULL AND LEAD(slots) OVER (ORDER BY datedate,startdate,enddate,slots) > 0 THEN 'end'
     WHEN slots IS NULL AND LEAD(slots) OVER (ORDER BY datedate,startdate,enddate,slots) IS NULL AND LAG(slots) OVER (ORDER BY datedate,startdate,enddate,slots) IS NULL  THEN NULL 
     WHEN slots IS NOT NULL THEN NULL 
END AS type,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY datedate,startdate,enddate,slots) AS row,
datedate
FROM mydates
) myalias
WHERE type IS NOT NULL;
```

Based on the data of the question's image, the output of the above query will produce something like this:

```
type     |     row     |     datedate
start           2            2020-09-29T17:29:59Z
end             3            2020-09-30T08:00:30Z
start           16           2020-09-30T14:30:30Z
end             23           2020-10-01T08:00:30Z
```

You can try it in this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/689e2/51)

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a gaps and islands problem.  The difference of row numbers is a simple method:

```
select min(datedate), max(datedate)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by datedate) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by slots order by datedate) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
where slots is null
group by (seqnum - seqnum_2);
```

Why this works is a little tricky to explain.  But if you look at the results of the subquery, you can see how the difference between the two calculations identifies adjacent rows with the same `slots` value.